# Use RSA encrypted AES-Key for encoding Text

Tags: java, aes, rsa, decode, encode

First, please excuse my bad english, this is not my native language.

i am trying to encode and then decode some text of different lengths.

I tried to encode some text with RSA algorithm in java. In the progress, I found out that RSA-encoding is limited to a specific size of bytes, so this approach doesn't fit my specs as my text could be large.

As I want to stay with a public and a private key only, I came up with the idea to use a 'hard-coded' AES key which will be encoded with RSA public key and than use this to encode the data. (see code)

```java
//harcoded secretkey base64 encoded 
private static final String secretkey_base64 = "xtnN6Pove5AovbLXtGRJKw==";

//this is how RSA key are generated
public static KeyPair genKeys() throws Exception {
   KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance( "RSA" );
   kpg.initialize(2048);
   KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
   return kp;
}

//here text should be encoded
public static String encodeText(String plainText, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception
{
   Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
   encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
   byte[] cipherText = encryptCipher.doFinal(CryptoUtil.secretkey_base64.getBytes(UTF_8));
   String encodedSecKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);

   SecretKeySpec k =  new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedSecKey), "AES");
   Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
   aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
   byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());

   return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteCipherText);
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work because the RSA encoded AES key is too long for AES encryption. Throws "Invalid AES key length: 256 bytes"

Does anyone have an idea how I could get the encryption running with this particular approach ?
Is this even possible, or do I have to use a different approach?

Thanks in advance.

//edit - Solved thanks to @ewramner
// here is the working solution:

```java
public static String encodeText(String plainText, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception
    {   
        KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        generator.init(128); // The AES key size in number of bits
        SecretKey secKey = generator.generateKey();

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.PUBLIC_KEY, publicKey);
        byte[] encSecKey = cipher.doFinal(secKey.getEncoded());


        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);
        byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encSecKey) + "#" + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteCipherText);
    }


public static String decodeText(String cipherText, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception
    {
        String[] split = cipherText.split("#");

        String encSecKey = split[0];
        String encText = split[1];

        byte[] bytesSecKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encSecKey);
        byte[] bytesText = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encText);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY, privateKey);
        byte[] decSecKey = cipher.doFinal(bytesSecKey);
        SecretKey secKey = new SecretKeySpec(decSecKey , 0, decSecKey .length, "AES");

        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKey);
        return new String(aesCipher.doFinal(bytesText));
    }
```

Comment: [Hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)

Comment: I know this is possible, but i tried to find a way where only privatekey is needed for decode.

Comment: Get rid of the hard-coded secret. Create a random AES key of the proper size and encrypt it with the RSA key. Then encrypt the plain text with the AES key. Then return the encrypted AES key followed by the encrypted plain text. As you are working with base64 you could separate the two with a character not used in base64. Then on the decoding side, split the text to get the encrypted key and decrypt it with the private RSA key. Use the decrypted AES key to decrypt the rest of the cipher text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try this :)

Comment: @ewramner it works, i added the solution to the inital post, thanks again